# APNs not working with iOS Parse Server App, Swift 2 Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

I am using a locally hosted Parse Server for my app backend. When I try to send pushes to my app on a device, the device doesn't receive them. The Parse dashboard also said the pushes weren't sent to any devices.

In my Xcode AppDelegate, I properly put functions in to connect to my server and even register a device token. My device's device token shows up in the Parse Server dashboard.

These are in my App Delegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

...

let types: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

...

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()

    PFPush.subscribeToChannelInBackground("") { (succeeded: Bool, error: NSError?) in
        if succeeded {
            print("ParseStarterProject successfully subscribed to push notifications on the broadcast channel.\n");
        } else {
            print("ParseStarterProject failed to subscribe to push notifications on the broadcast channel with error = %@.\n", error)
        }
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.\n")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@\n", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    PFPush.handlePush(userInfo)

    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

I also went through the following steps:

- Create an iOS Development SSL Certificate, and upload it to the server
- Create a provisioning profile, which included my development device
- Enable Push Notifications in the Xcode Project Settings Capabilities

Yet, I still cant' receive notifications on the device when I send them from my server.

Any suggestions? I've been working on this for a long time and none of the tutorials I've been through have been successful. Is there a step I'm missing, or perhaps one I should be doing differently?

Comment: Make sure you are sending them over the Apple push sandbox environment not the production environment.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with either of those two, they never came up before in my research or tutorials. Could you please elaborate more?  @Grunt

Comment: Pushes get delivered via an Apple server, there are two servers, one for development and one for production, the two are not interchangeable (i.e. if your push token is from a development build of your app then it won't work on the production environment). I suppose Parse takes care of this for you, but maybe you just need to double check that is the case and the pushes are going over the development environment, which is also known as the sandbox environment (as its url has "sandbox" in its name).

Comment: Where do I check to see if it is going over the development environment? Is that app end or server end? @Grunt

Comment: Its a server side thing, but now that parse.com website/service itself has shut down I've no idea where to check - as you are hosting a local parse server you'll have to look where and how its configured/configurable.

Comment: Actually, is that why its not working? http://blog.parse.com/announcements/moving-on/

Comment: As the server admin in charge of the server, Evan is using here, I can say that parse shutting down is not the issue as we are running on the open source stand alone server of the Parse Server GitHub.  Also, I have the apple push notifications configured for Development/Sandbox.

Comment: "Create a provisioning profile". What are you using this for? Are you building an archive/.ipa? If so then your app is probably a production build not a development build and consequently the push token will be a production token. You need to ensure you are running a development build configuration of the app as you are using development pushes.

Comment: I'm just downloading/"Running"/Building this app straight from Xcode to a hardware device to test it. I am trying to receive notifications on my hardware device

Comment: I haven't archived anything -- I'm not using this as a production app, I just want to test it under development for now

Comment: How do I check that my app is running a development build?

Comment: It's in the setting for a scheme.

Comment: What do I search for in build settings to find that?

Comment: I don't have Xcode in front of me, but a drop down in one of the menu items is edit scheme or similar. You can see it from there, but if you are installing and running via Xcode then it will be dev by default unless somebody changed it on purpose.

Comment: Okay it says under Build Active Architecture that its set to Debug. I'd assume that's what you are getting at...

Comment: I've still got no luck. Maybe is the deviceToken that the functions in my AppDelegate generated a production token and not a development token? If so, do you know how I might check that?

Comment: Thats it. The only other possibilities are: the token is stale an d the new one isn't getting used on the server, there is no network connectivity on the device, you are sending silent pushes to the app but the app is terminated, you made a mistake with the certificate generation side of things.

Comment: How do I determine if the token is stale?

Comment: Also, these are basically all of the steps I've followed to create a certificate: https://quickblox.com/developers/How_to_create_APNS_certificates Is anything missing or wrong from there?